# Accentuated literals in Java

Tags: java, unicode, literals

I tried to type char literals for accentuated vowels in Java, but the compilers says something like: *unclosed character literal*

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
 char [] a = {'à', 'á', 'â', 'ä' };
```

I've tried using Unicode `'\u00E0'` but for some reason they don't match with my code:

```
 for( char c : string.toCharArray() ) {
     if( c == a[i] ) {
         // I've found a funny letter 
     }
 }
```

The `if` never evaluates to true, no matter what I put in my string.

Here's the [complete program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941899/i-need-a-function-to-convert-lower-case-to-upper-case-in-java/1942323#1942323) I'm trying to code.

Comment: don't you need to iterate through the array, where's "i" assigned/incremented?

Comment: @curtisk: Yeap, you're right, I didn't specify that. I included the original code where I'm using that , it is more complex and there I'm comparing as you said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code should be compiled with the correct encoding:

```
javac -encoding UTF-8 Foo.java
```

---

There'll be an encoding mismatch there somewhere.

```
public class Foo {
  char [] a = {'à', 'á', 'â', 'ä' };  
}
```

The above code saved as UTF-8 should become the hex dump:

```
70 75 62 6C 69 63 20 63 6C 61 73 73 20 46 6F 6F         public class Foo
20 7B 0D 0A 20 20 63 68 61 72 20 5B 5D 20 61 20          {__  char [] a
3D 20 7B 27 C3 A0 27 2C 20 27 C3 A1 27 2C 20 27         = {'__', '__', '
C3 A2 27 2C 20 27 C3 A4 27 20 7D 3B 20 20 0D 0A         __', '__' };  __
7D 0D 0A 0D 0A                                          }____
```

The UTF-8 value for code point U+00E0 (à) is `C3 A0`.

The code should be compiled with the correct encoding:

```
javac -encoding UTF-8 Foo.java
```

*There is an outside chance that à will be represented by the combining sequence U+0061 U+0300. This is the [NFD](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) form (I've never come across a text editor that used it as a default for text entry). As [Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942383/accentuated-literals-in-java/1942425#1942425) out, it is often better to always use \uXXXX escape sequences - it is less ambiguous.*

You also need to check your input device (file/console/etc.)

As a last resort, you can dump your `char`s as hex `System.out.format("%04x", (int) c);` and try manually decoding them with a [character inspector](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/09/java-character-inspector-application.html) to find out what they are.

Comment: Excellent explanation. In a nutshell: save (and compile) file as UTF-8.

Answer (score 5):

For Unicode chacters to work, you must be certain that javac reads it in the same encoding as it is written.

You will save yourself a lot of trouble by just using the \uXXXX notation.

Answer (score 1):

Look up the Unicode character values, and use literals of the form `\uxxxx`.

U+00e is a with a grave accent, e.g.

```
char aacute = '\u00e1';
```

The next question is where your string came from. Are you sure it has these characters? As composed characters? Better print some out in hex and have a look.

You might need to normalize (in Java 1.6 or with icu4j).

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work for me in a quick test:

```
static char [] a = {'à', 'á', 'â', 'ä' };


    public static boolean foundMatch(String s){

        boolean test = false;
        for(int i=0;i < a.length;i++){
            String t = String.valueOf(a[i]);
            test = s.contains(t);
            if (test) return true;
    }
        return test;
    }
```

Comment: i guess it depends on using the right tools.  in this case, a unicode capable text editor.  (AFAIR, Java works mostly in unicode, but not so sure about the compiler)

Comment: You can tell the compiler about the encoding used in your sources by passing the `-encoding` option, e.g. `javac -encoding utf8 ...`

Comment: @curtisk: Yeap, that's what I thought. Actually that's how it would compile on my old Windows machine. It turns out my new compiler wasn't using UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what you need to accomplish (i.e. why you need to find accentuated characters in a string), I'll hazard a guess that you need to do more than merely check if there are accented characters present in a piece of input. On the risk of telling you something you already know:

- If you need to filter them out of a text string I recommend you use whitelisting instead of blacklisting.
- If you need to sort them alphabetically regardless of accentuation, use [java.text.Collator](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) instead of a roll-your-own system.
- If you need to replace the accented characters by their 'base' characters, the [Collator](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) should again be of help (the decomposition stuff inside it), but I haven't done this before, so I can't tell you how to do so exactly.

Comment: I'm posting an answer to someone new to programming. This is more for learning purposes. The original answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941899/i-need-a-function-to-convert-lower-case-to-upper-case-in-java/1942323#1942323 Thanks for the answer.